# Google API call to get new access_token return 404 not found

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I am trying to [refresh an access token (offline access)](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline)
I called this `POST` request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?refresh_token=xxx&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=refresh_token
```

the response is supposed to be like this

```
{
 "access_token":"1/fFAGRNJru1FTz70BzhT3Zg",
 "expires_in":3920,
 "token_type":"Bearer"
}
```

but I am only getting `404 Not Found`.
Is something wrong with my Google API call?
I already set the `access_type=offline`.

Comment: I think that the endpoint works, when the refresh_token, client_id and client_secret can be used. Although I'm not sure about your method which are trying to retrieve the access token, as a test how about retrieving access token using curl? For example, it's ``curl -X POST "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token?refresh_token=xxx&client_id=xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=xxx&grant_type=refresh_token"`` In my environment, it works. But if it didn't work at your environment, I'm sorry.